# finding the datatypes inside a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For my requirement, I need to find the locations of all the instances between 2 numpy arrays that have different data types

array 1 can be so : `numpy.array(['1',3, 9, None])`

array 2 can be so : `numpy.array([5,4,3,2])`

if they all were of the same type then I can do array 1 - array 2 diff to get the numerical differences. This won't be possible in the above scenario. So, as part of my data quality check, I would like to explicitly flag the indexes of array 1 that are of a different type than array 2. What would be the most pythonic way to do so?

Comment: With the `None` the first will be object dtype, with a mix string, int and None.  The 2nd is int dtype.

Comment: Correct, but I need to be a bit more granular than that.  If there is a type difference between each elem then I need to explicitly flag that hey there is a mismatch here. So for example None - 2,  would be flagged but 3 - 4 wouldn't

Comment: what about `'1' - 2` ? or `'bob' -  'b'` or `'3' - ''5'`? etc?

Comment: @JoranBeasley : Good question. So more context here : I am improving our data testing tool that does comparisons of financial data. In one of the steps I am explicitly converting string numerics to floats and then doing the differences. But let's set that aside for now. I should also say that we are doing row by row compares which IMO is too slow. So I was exploring a col vs col compare using numpy. The above question is a generic question I wanted to ask. Something like 
numpy.where(type(x)!=type(y)) but of course that doesn't exist in numpy (that i know)

Comment: so `'1' - 5 = <what goes here>`  ... it sounds like you do expect -4? ... why do you need like types? is there something other than floaty strings and ints/floats and None's?  if it can be a float wouldnt you want to just do float - float?

Comment: @JoranBeasley : Correct. The dangerzones are mostly Nones, but rare occurences there will be some noisy data that fell through because of a bug in the  dev's code. We have seen instances where we are expecting say a 6 digit number and instead we get 6 digit letters ...lol

Comment: ahh that makes it a bit harder as my solution below wont work if they put something not able to be converted to a float (nones become nan's which makes the result nans which is easy to flag) .... could you use pandas? that would simplify it I think

Comment: @JoranBeasley: yes! If it was just Nones, I wouldn't even bother posting. I think for now I am gonna brute force it numpy.where(x!=y) and whatever is in that list just check for type  before doing the diff.

Comment: Object dtype arrays are list like.  Most processing occurs at list comprehension speeds.  I'd focus on testing a single element.  `np.frompyfunc` is also handy when working with object arrays,  It isn't faster.

Answer (score 0):

A testing function:

```
def foo(a,b):
    try:
        a-b
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

the two sample arrays:

```
In [22]: array1 = np.array(['1',3, 9, None])
    ...: array2 = np.array([5,4,3,2])
```

test the 2 arrays - ones that work:

```
In [23]: [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(array1,array2)) if foo(a,b)]
Out[23]: [1, 2]
```

ones that don't:

```
In [24]: [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(array1,array2)) if not foo(a,b)]
Out[24]: [0, 3]
```

another way to use `foo`, getting a boolean array:

```
In [26]: f = np.frompyfunc(foo, 2, 1)
In [27]: f(array1,array2)
Out[27]: array([False, True, True, False], dtype=object)
```

actually it is still `object` dtype, but the values are boolean.

```
In [28]: f(array1,array2).astype(bool)
Out[28]: array([False,  True,  True, False])
```

and the problem items in `array1`:

```
In [29]: array1[~_]
Out[29]: array(['1', None], dtype=object)
```

The test function could be more elaborate.

Comment: Thank you. Let me try some parts of this and get back to you. I have something similar. Sorry for the late reply as today was a holiday.

Comment: I like the enumerate and it seems that approach should get me what I want smoothly.  I have to test this out on larger datasets in the 40 mil range and see how the performance is. Thank you.